# App freezes when a tableViewController is opened

Tags: ios, swift

First want to know how can I debug where the issue is, what is stalling the main thread indefinitely. I read somewhere that as soon as my app freezes, i should pause it and see the threads and i'll able to see what is taking up so long. I did that but I cant identify the cause.
[image: Screenshot of threads in frozen app state]

Secondly, I should also mention my scenario because the freeze is always reproducible. I open a `tableViewController`on tap of a `UILabel` (through `TapGestureRecongniser`). The user can select multiple cells in the `tableViewController` and the `UILabel` reflects the values, user selected in `tableViewController`. I have a central ContentManager which handles the content of the app. The `tableViewController` changes a list in the `ContentManager` and `UILabel` fetches that list to update it self. Everything is working fine till here. If I open the `TableViewController` again, the app freezes. This only happens if the user has changed the selected cells. If user opens `tableViewController` but does not change any cell's selected state and presses back, app does not freezes on opening it again. This is code of my `tableViewController`

```
import UIKit
import SwiftEventBus

class InterestsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Select Your Interests"

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Select", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = false

        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
        setPreSelectedCells()
    }

    func setPreSelectedCells() {
        var interestList = ContentManager.shared.getInterests()!

        if interestList.count > 0 {

            for i in 0..<interestList.endIndex {

                let interest  = interestList[i]
                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: i)

                if interest.isSelected {

                    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
                    self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath);
                } else {

                    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
                    self.tableView(self.tableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func addTapped() {
        print("interests selected")
        print(tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.count)

        if let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {

            var selectedInterests : [String] = []
            for indexPath in indexPaths {
                selectedInterests.append(ContentManager.shared.getInterests()![indexPath.section].id)
            }

            if selectedInterests.count > 0 {
                ApiCallsManager.updateInterests(selectedInterests)
                navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        if ContentManager.shared.getInterests() != nil {
            return ContentManager.shared.getInterests()!.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView {

        let headerView: UIView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        return headerView
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("InterestsTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! InterestsTableViewCell

        let interest = ContentManager.shared.getInterests()![indexPath.section]
        cell.interestLabel.text = interest.getCategory()
        cell.picture.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: interest.picture)!)

        if cell.selected {
            cell.filter.alpha = 0.85
        } else {
            cell.filter.alpha = 0.3
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? InterestsTableViewCell {
                    cell.filter.alpha = 0.85

            if let count = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.count {
                navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Select (\(count))", style: .Plain, target:    self, action: #selector(addTapped))
        } else {
                navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Select", style: .Plain, target:    self, action: #selector(addTapped))
                navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? InterestsTableViewCell  {
            cell.filter.alpha = 0.3

            if let count = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.count {
                navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Select (\(count))", style: .Plain, target:    self, action: #selector(addTapped))
            } else {
                navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Select", style: .Plain, target:    self, action: #selector(addTapped))
                navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Very hard to tell what's the problem without seeing any code - could you post a snapshot of your code. Thanks.

Comment: @tanzolone Please check edited question. I added the code for `tableViewController` I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Why are you calling self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath  when this should be an event as the row is selected.

Comment: @Dominic no, when a cell is selected programatically, selection events are not fired. you have to fire them manually.